# Make a submit button outside the form element - isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to make a button outside the form element that will check whether or not the inputs has been filled, if they are, then submit the form, if not, do something else (like prompting an alert or something).

I have made this fiddle, and it will not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/fe9Nk/

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:alert('submitted');" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="inp_name">
  <input type="text" id="inp_address">
  <input type="text" id="inp_zipcode">
  <input type="text" id="inp_city">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>

<a href="#" id="to-top">CLICK ME TO SUBMIT FORM OUTSIDE FORM ELEMENT</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var bas_name = $("#inp_name").val();
var bas_address = $("#inp_address").val();
var bas_zipcode = $("#inp_zipcode").val();
var bas_city = $("#inp_city").val();

$("#to-top").click(function() {
    if(bas_name == "" && bas_address == "" && bas_zipcode == "" && bas_city == "") {
        alert("nonoonnono!");
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the variable scope. You can do this:-

```
$("#to-top").click(function () {
    var bas_name = $("#inp_name").val();
    var bas_address = $("#inp_address").val();
    var bas_zipcode = $("#inp_zipcode").val();
    var bas_city = $("#inp_city").val();

    if (bas_name == "" && bas_address == "" && bas_zipcode == "" && bas_city == "") {
        alert("nonoonnono!");
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/fe9Nk/1/)

This issue occurred since, you have kept all the variables outside the click event. So, it will always store the empty values on page load and thus your code doesn't works.
But, while clicking the anchor tag, you need to get the current values in the textboxes and then do all the validations.

Hope, you got my point!

Comment: Yes, that should solve it...technically it's not scope but timing. Those variables are accessible to the event handler but they are getting set too early.

Comment: @MattBrowne: Yeah, right. You got the main concept basically!

Comment: It works, but how can it be that in my real life application the form only jumps to the top when doing .submit()? In the example it works just fine with the alert on the form action, but when I inserted my URL to handle the data and stuff, it only jumps to the top, doing nothing more.

Comment: @Dueify: I think you will need to prevent the default action of anchor tag here using [`e.preventdefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). Updated code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/fe9Nk/7/)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MD8jayS2 I tried with that, didn't work, though it doesn't jump to the top now...

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value after the click

```
$("#to-top").click(function() {
var bas_name = $("#inp_name").val();
var bas_address = $("#inp_address").val();
var bas_zipcode = $("#inp_zipcode").val();
var bas_city = $("#inp_city").val();

if(bas_name == "" && bas_address == "" && bas_zipcode == "" && bas_city == "") {
    alert("nonoonnono!");
} else {
    $("form").submit();
}
});
```

Comment: Works great, only problem is I can submit the form with only 1 input filled, and I thought I asked for all the inputs to be filled out?

Comment: in the if statement you should use OR instead of AND

Comment: Ok thanks. My only problem is in my live application it doesn't submit the form, it only jumps to the top of the page, but doesn't go on with the submitting.... weird because it works in the fiddle with the alert in the form action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#to-top", function() {
    //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into the form funcion **onsubmit**, where you can call the js function what you wrote and return true or false. Here is a simple example:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

After that, it's easy to call the form submit from wherever you want with jQuery.

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

or with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```